# How to map emacs multi-modifier keys in vim?

Tags: vim, key-mapping

I want to be able to map the multi-modifier keys of emacs in vim.

I am trying this for exiting vim:

```
imap <C-x><C-c> <ESC>ZZ
```

However, this does not work.

Comment: Are you trying to make keybindings of emacs apply to vim or vim keybindings apply to emacs?

Comment: @Braiam I am using vim and trying to make some emacs keybindings in insert mode. I edited the question

Comment: This seems to be a quirk of the CTRL-C mapping, which is the interrupt key. For some reason, this mapping only starts working after tweaking the Ctrl-C key in some way. Try `imap <C-c> <Nop>` followed by `iunmap <C-c>` and your mapping may start working.